# How to split audio and video separately from a given video file using MLT?

Tags: android, audio, video, mlt

I would like to split both `audio` and `video` from a given input video file. After surfing in internet I came to know that it is possible using `ffmpeg`.I am going to implement the above functionality in the `Android application`.In ffmpeg it has lot of build procedures, so i would prefer `MLT` or any other package available for this.Anyone please guide me about how can i achieve these concepts with `MLT` or any other frame works if available.

**Given input video file(contains both Audio and Video)**

**Expected output audio file(contains only audio not video)**

**Expected output Video file(contains only Video not audio)**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MLT does not provide simple demuxing or splitting functions. It brings every input into the uncompressed domain for eventual output after processing. I suggest that you use FFmpeg.

Comment: Hi, @Dan I saw your profile and found you are a lead dev of MLT. Can you point us to useful resources for integrating FFMpeg with MLT or using MLT alone in the android framework? Thanks  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51502532/how-can-i-make-android-app-on-mlt-framework